# How do I separate an int into substrings/sub-ints?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, split, int

I want to split a number into different numbers.(e.g. 123456 -> 123,456 or 12,3456 or 123,45,6...etc). They have to be in the same order as well. So one method I was thinking was putting each digit of the number into an array first. Then I would go through the array and find each combination of them. But I think this method would have a long run-time to find all possible combination especially if the number can be split more than 2 times. Would there be a more efficient method in doing this?

Comment: primarily opinion-based 
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @JFPicard So algorithm complexity is opinion based according to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would there be a more efficient method in doing this?

No.

There will be 2<sup>n-1</sup> combinations, e.g. for a 6-digit number, 2<sup>5</sup> = 32 combinations.

Think of it like this: Each "space" between digits can be either separated or not, true/false, 1/0, i.e. a "bit", so you can determine split combination using a 5-bit number:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
 ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
 0 0 0 0 0   ->  123456
 0 0 0 0 1   ->  12345,6
 0 0 0 1 0   ->  1234,56
  . . . .
 1 1 1 1 0   ->  1,2,3,4,56
 1 1 1 1 1   ->  1,2,3,4,5,6
```